# netbeans no library found for this namespace

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, maven, primefaces

I've searched around but cannot fine a definitive solution. I'm using netbeans+Maven and am trying to upgrade from Primefaces 2.2.1 to 3.0.M3 - when I change the index.xhtml taglib to  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" netbeans throws the 'no library found for this namespace' error.

The index.xhtml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>            
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Run Test" action="selecttype" />
        <h:commandButton value="Manage Methods" action="addmethod" />
        <h:commandButton value="Manage Data" action="managedata" />
        <p:tagCloud model="#{tagCloudBean.model}" />  
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

So the new taglib and p:tagCloud line are what netbeans says are not working - when I run the program I see the 3 buttons above the message "Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.org/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.".

For Maven I've updated these parts of the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.M3</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net.m2</id>
        <name>java.net m2 repo</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
     </repository>
</repositories>
```

and commented out the old prime-repo repository info.

I have got primefaces-3.0.M3.jar as a local dependency - this seems to be ok as all java class files using the library are referencing it ok. The primefaces-3.0.M3.jar binary is also in my WEB-INF/lin folder. I've seen a lot of people having weird issues with netbeans and am not sure if I'm simply missing something or if its the IDE. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xmlns` is wrong for the Primefaces component.  Try changing the url to `http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui` as per the [Primefaces Getting Started guide](http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html).

**UPDATE 08-08-2013:**

As of this moment the correct namespace as listed in the following link is:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Comment: If I revert that address back to http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui and I use, for example, the new FileUpload - Multiple code it still renders the 2.2.1 version, not the 3.0.M3 version.

If I try to add a strictly primefaces v3 feature such as Log I then get a similar message to the original problem:
"p:log> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui, but no tag was defined for name: log"

Comment: Otherwise it does seem to work, but only for non v3 components

Comment: That's because that namespace is the version 2 namespace. I don't believe you got a real answer, just a 'revert back to previous version'.

Answer (score 4):

Actually if you are using Primefaces 3.0 M4 then the xmlns changed to:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Comment: I just started using netbeans, and stumbled upon the 'no library found for this namespace' error. This answer makes the error go away.. Ref : http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1431 for official Primefaces blog entry supporting this answer

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution:

1. Right click on the EE project.
2. Click on `Frameworks`.
3. Click on `JavaServer Faces`.
4. Click on `Components`
5. Check `PrimeFaces`
6. Click OK

This solves the problem. However, the error icon will still appear in the left panel of our project. (Not in the code). So you must copy all your code (whatever) `.xhtml` and recreate it, paste the code you wrote and run.

In other words, you must recreate the file that is giving you problems.

Comment: NetBeans 8.1 provides an outdated version 5.0 of Primefaces as 6.2 is already out. Please don't recommend out-dated versions. The better way is to create an own library under NetBeans and add the up-to-date JAR to it.

Answer (score 1):

in case of anyone still looking for an answer for this,

just right click your EE project -> select project properties -> Frameworks -> components and select primefaces.

works on Netbeans 8.1